# How to omit full qualifier when using Datomic/Datalog query?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

I have the following in a Datalog query: `'[:find ... :where [(wef-backend.app.identity/past-expiry? ?expiry)]]]` Due to how Datomic/Datalog works I must fully qualify the past-expiry? function, even though it is available in the namespace where I wrote this query is there some clever trick that would let me omit the full qualifier? I tried syntax quoting on the query but that doesn’t work, as it fully qualifies the `?expiry, etc` variables too. Essentially I would like to fully qualify some symbols in that quoted expression but not others

Comment: I'd assume, that a ns-alias would work? `::alias/expiry?`